# Triple Booting Windows 8.1, Ubuntu and OSX Mavericks

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, osx-mavericks

I'm currently dual booting Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10 using the GRUB2 bootloader. Windows is installed on my C drive and Ubuntu on my D drive. How do I triple boot with OSX installed on my D drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.robertshady.com/content/how-triple-boot-osx-maverick-windows-7-and-debian-linux-your-hackintosh-wgigabyte-z87x-ud5h-

Check out this link for multi-boot, you may have to make some changes for Drive letters and etc.  But it's the general idea.

Comment: post your answer yourself instead of a link